# Selecting a parent element (without using Jquery)

Tags: javascript, dom

I just need to access the parent div where I have a button changing his siblings divs.
A code example can explain better:

```
<div class="parent">  <!-- This is structure repeats N times -->
    <div class="divToToggleVisiblity divA">trololo A</div>
    <div class="divToToggleVisiblity divB">trololo B</div>
    <button onClick="toggleThem(this)">This button will toggle above divs</button>
</div>


function toggleThem(a){  // something like this, BUT without Jquery
    $(a).closest(".parent").find(".divA").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's what [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.parentNode) is for:

```
a.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.divA');
```

Comment: What is "a" in this example:?

Comment: @zero_cool it follows the original question, in which case `a` is the `button` element.

Answer (score 2):

```
function toggleThem(elem) {
    elem.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('divA')[0].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined`. Don't forget that `getElementsByClassName` returns a `nodeList`.